# How can I place my object onto a UV sphere to give it a rounded appearance?

Tags: modeling

Blender newbie here, I'm trying to make a character for the first time, for the head I used a UV Sphere and I'm making all the stuff on its head, but I made it flat.
[image]
As the title says, is there a way to overlay my object onto the UV Sphere to make it rounded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new plane behind *Plane.001*, subdivide it, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with *Sphere.001* as *Target*, disable it for the moment:

[image]

Give a *Surface Deform* modifier to *Plane.001* with the new plane as *Target*, click on the *Bind* button:

[image]

Enable the visibility of the *Shrinkwrap* modifier of the new plane, it will wrap on the sphere and your other object will deform as well. If it doesn't deform enough, add topology:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I tried it and it works but it's kinda glitchy : https://imgur.com/a/FopWTv1 and https://imgur.com/a/X50Zw8n 
Maybe I did something wrong or it's because the shape of my object is bad : https://imgur.com/a/tCOGKkJ

Comment: are you using my method?Maybe share your file:https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yeah but I probably made a mistake I guess, sorry, here's the link : https://blend-exchange.com/b/dZJlZbDG

Comment: I've edited my answer, if your french you can join our Discord here: https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Comment: Thanks it works fine ! I made a mistake the first time, I use a subdivision modifier instead of a simple subdivision with right click.
Also yes I'm french I'll join it, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are wanting you'd have to change your approach a little bit, currently it looks like you have made a faceplate and an eye brow, but you made them with thickness, so if you project them onto the sphere it would flatten and you'd have both sides overlapping.

So instead you can make your shapes as flat planes (no thickness, you can just delete the back and sides of your current objects). Then add a Shrinkwrap modifier, and set the target as your sphere, and wrap method as "target normals", then add a Solidify modifier after the shrink wrap to add the thickness to your objects.

Alternatively If you are wanting to interactively move your points and have them stick to the sphere, you can turn on Snap, and set Snap to to Face Project, and now while in edit mode you can have your vertices snap to other shapes when ever you move them over it.